# Why can I boot only Windows and not Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

Recently built a computer but I am unable to boot into Ubuntu. Hardware that might be relevant...

- Asus ROG Strix B550F (Wifi)
- G Skill 3600 c16
- RTX 3070ti xc3
- Samsung 980 1TB nvme m.2

I have tried the following

1. Formatting the drive with GPT and MBR with an EFI System Partition, a space for the root (/) directory, and the rest for /home.
2. Boot with CSM on and off.
3. Boot with Fast Boot on and off.
4. Boot with secure Boot on and off.
5. Dual boot with Windows.
6. Install only Windows 10 on the drive.
7. Booting Ubuntu from a SSD I have installed on another computer.

BIOS is updated to the latest stable version (2403). In all the above cases, Ubuntu will not boot, it just gets stuck on the Republic of Gamers splash screen. Windows boots with no problem. When I dual boot with Windows, GRUB does show up, but again, will only successfully boot Windows not Ubuntu. Also, I bought a new Samsung NVME thinking the first was faulty but got the same results. There are no other drives connected except when I tried booting from the other SSD.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu did you try?

Comment: Do not even try with CSM & MBR. Only use UEFI & gpt partitioning. Have you updated Samsung SSD with latest firmware also? My NVMe Samsung had a bootable ISO to update just my model, Windows not required. Need to be using newest Ubuntu to have latest kernel & drivers & install nVidia driver/restricted drives using safe boot. ASUS ROG Strix G15 Linux 5.13 stable series or Linux 5.14 req'd. Comparison of Ubuntu & Arch
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=arch-linux-5900hx&num=1 Also: Asus Rog Strix B550 Disable IOMMU

Comment: I tried the latest version (20.04.2). Samsung 980 (non-pro version) doesn’t have any firmware only the pro version. I can get a root shell if I boot into safe mode in Linux I will try updating the drivers that way when I get home. When I installed though I did check the box to install third party drivers.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi

Comment: @oldfred booted into recovery mode and installed the graphics drivers from there and was able to boot! Thank you! I did not think of this since I checked the box to install the drivers on the install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @oldfred for pointing me in the right direction. The solution was to boot into recovery mode (the only way I was able to get GRUB to show up was when dual-booting with Windows) and installing the latest graphics drivers. I followed this guide to install the drivers. https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux/ .Restarted and was able to boot into Ubuntu.